# Instantiation of chaincode fails with Fabric v1.2.0 due to missing escc

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Setup is working fine with Fabric 1.1.0
When I tried to upgrade to Fabric 1.2.0, I got the following errors during instantiation of chaincode saying that „escc was not found“

```
[golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 072 building chaincode with ldflagsOpt: '-ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags '-static'"'
2018-08-09 20:00:31.815 UTC [golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 073 building chaincode with tags: 
2018-08-09 20:01:01.188 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> WARN 074 Endorsement with plugin for {plugin: escc, channel: channel3, tx: 01427f701088a8e8cdfe2b543892af33d4012a661474f88670c8e2739717062f, chaincode: lscc}  failed: plugin with name escc wasn't found
```

My Fabric peer setup is not based on docker images, but I did install fabric myself using with git clone and build (git reset --hard v1.2.0; make peer...). It is a fresh installed Ubuntu Linux 16.04.
Didn't change any setup.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure your [core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml) file is also updated to v1.2

Comment: This is the solution. core.yaml v1.2 has many new entries. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: can you please then press then up arrow to the left of my comment? :)